# Upper hemicontinuity question with an example

Tags: continuity, fixed-point-theorems

[image]

I am studying the definition of upper hemicontinuity. The definition says a correspondence $F:X\rightrightarrows Y$ is said to be upper hemicontinuous at $x$, if, for every open subset $O\subseteq Y$ with $F(x)\subseteq O$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$F(N_{\delta,X}(x))\subseteq O.$$

In the example I attached, there is an open set $O=(y_2-\varepsilon,y_1+\varepsilon)\cup (y_4-\varepsilon,y_3+\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$, which contains $F(x)$. Then there is $\delta>0$ (in fact, all $\delta>0$) such that $F(x')\subset O$ for any $x'$ in the neighborhood of $x$ with $\delta$.

I believe this should be wrong. Otherwise, Kakutani's fixed point theorem does not go through. Can you help me to correct my understanding about upper hemicontinuity?

The (middle) line $f(x)=x$ is not part of correspondence $F$. I drew $f(x)=x$ to show that Kakutani's fixed point theorem doesn't hold in $F$. Thanks!!

Comment: Upper-hemicontinuity is not the only condition in Kakutani's fixed point theorem. Your relation is upper-hemicontinuous and compact and non-empty-valued (if your definition of correspondence doesn't require non-emptiness), but not convex-valued, so Kakutani doesn't apply.

Comment: By the way, you might get a faster answer to this sort of question at Economics Stack Exchange, since pure mathematicians don't often think about correspondences. Asking this question here, it would probably be advisable to state Kakutani's Fixed Point Theorem, as lots of people would be unfamiliar.

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas! I really appreciate for your answer! I checked again and you are right! The image of correspondence should be convex!